# Combine Meteor and Express

Tags: meteor

I am evaluating Meteor as an alternative to developing real-time capabilities using socket.io and it looks like awesome framework for single page real-time apps. It is great time saver that enables developer focusing on the business logic of the app, rather than writing boilerplate code. However, I find it still pre-mature for a medium size app with multiple pages/routings and REST api. Plus, number of features like i18n are still not available which requires some time investment to develop by myself.

I think that it would be great if I could combine Meteor and Express and use Meteor in use cases where it really shines.

Is it possible to develop an app using standard Express/Mongo stack and use Meteor for only specific part of the app where I need real time collaboration?

For example, can I share a session between Express/Connect and Meteor?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This does not directly answer your question, but I thought I'd throw it out there:

You should check out the community packages on [atmosphere](http://atmospherejs.com/). Specifically, I'd recommend having a look at [iron-router](http://atmospherejs.com/iron/router) and [i18n](http://atmospherejs.com/anti/i18n) (I'll note I have not used the latter).

I've built a large production app that uses iron-router and it's running smoothly. You may also be able to use its [server-side-routing](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/DOCS.md#server-side-routing) capabilities to implement your REST api.

Comment: Thank you, David! I will check meteor-router. But, would be interested to hear from people who did integration of Meteor<->Express or maybe Meteor<->Django or Ruby...